# Can I have vim highlight code in R markup?

Tags: r, vim

Say I have an `.Rmd` file like this:

````
The total number of steps per day can also be calculated
using `tapply`.
```{r}
tapply(d$steps, INDEX=d$date, FUN=sum)[1:5]
```
What seems to be different is that, per default, `xtabs`
returns 0 for `NA` values and `tapply` returns `NA`.
````

In my terminal window, this looks like this:

[image]

It would be great if somehow I could inform vim that the `R` chunk is actually `R` code which it could highlight just as it does when working in an actual `.R` file.

Is this possible?

Comment: I would suggest sticking to this page: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can. This code is taken from [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file).

Put this in the `~/.vim/r.vim` file (if any of these files do not exist, create them)

```
function! TextEnableCodeSnip(filetype,start,end,textSnipHl) abort
  let ft=toupper(a:filetype)
  let group='textGroup'.ft
  if exists('b:current_syntax')
    let s:current_syntax=b:current_syntax
    " Remove current syntax definition, as some syntax files (e.g. cpp.vim)
    " do nothing if b:current_syntax is defined.
    unlet b:current_syntax
  endif
  execute 'syntax include @'.group.' syntax/'.a:filetype.'.vim'
  try
    execute 'syntax include @'.group.' after/syntax/'.a:filetype.'.vim'
  catch
  endtry
  if exists('s:current_syntax')
    let b:current_syntax=s:current_syntax
  else
    unlet b:current_syntax
  endif
  execute 'syntax region textSnip'.ft.'
  \ matchgroup='.a:textSnipHl.'
  \ start="'.a:start.'" end="'.a:end.'"
  \ contains=@'.group
endfunction
```

Now you can use

````
:call TextEnableCodeSnip(  'r',   '```{r}',   '```', 'SpecialComment')
````

As long as there is an r.vim syntax file.

You could also automatically call this method every time you open a .Rmd file:

````
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.Rmd :call TextEnableCodeSnip(  'r',   '```{r}',   '```', 'SpecialComment')
````

If you wanted to highlight with r followed by any number of characters you can use regular expressions:

````
:call TextEnableCodeSnip(  'r',   '```{r.*}',   '```', 'SpecialComment')
````

Or in your .vimrc:

````
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.Rmd :call TextEnableCodeSnip(  'r',   '```{r.*}',   '```', 'SpecialComment')
````

The `.*` regular expression means any repeating character. So `r.*` means `r` followed by any number of characters.

Therefore this will work with

````
```{r whatever you want to put here}`
    Some r code here
```
````

Comment: Beautiful. Any chance you knew how it could handle `r` chunks like 
```{r fig.height=4}
par(mar=c(3,3,1,1))
plot(d$dateint, d$steps)
``` i.e. where there's some little more in the `{r ...}` part?

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand your question. Are you asking if you can have r markup for just one line. I'm not an r user and don't know much about it.

Comment: What I mean is, I'm using your code now in my `.vimrc` file and it works perfectly. However, when a r chunk starts with `{r fig.height=5}`, rather then just `{r}`, then the code will not recognize the chunk and therefore not highlight it.

Comment: Yes you can, I have edited my answer with the new information. Please accept it if you find it correctly answers the question :) Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You might also be interested in my [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168), which is based on the Vim Tip in @Zach's answer. It simplifies the setup of such syntax regions.

The setup would be like this (e.g. in `~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim`):

`````
call SyntaxRange#Include('^````{r}', '^````', 'r', 'SpecialComment')
`````

Comment: link-only , but useful ... maybe should be a comment?

Comment: @BenBolker Alright, I've added an example how to set this up, to contrast this with the other answer.